# MouseEnter and MouseLeave events seem slow

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to change the background color of the Panel and Label, they seem to change slightly slower than each other.
Despite having both of them set to change upon Enter/Leave of both Panel and Label, I can notice just half a second of a difference when changing.

Does anyone know how I can get them both to change at the exact same time regardless if the mouse is over either?

```
private void panel3_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(125, 170, 170, 170);
    label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
}

private void panel3_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(125, 45, 45, 45);
    label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
}

private void label2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(125, 170, 170, 170);
    label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
}

private void label2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(125, 45, 45, 45);
    label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
}
```

Here's an example of what it's doing.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpmUq.gif)

Comment: Do you mean there is a lag between the change of background color of the Panel and the change of background color of the label ? For which event exactly? Also, you don't never seem to change the label back color to something else than transparent. Can you provide a full working example that we can try?

Comment: Remove all the `label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;`. Assign to the `MouseEnter` event of `label2` the same handler of `panel3` (so you have just 2 event handlers: 1 used by the panel and 1 used by both the panel and the label). That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will keep getting this flickering due to the background's image/drawing of the parent container as I can see from your [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpmUq.gif). Please consider using double buffered controls through sub-classing to reduce that flickering.

```cs
class DBPanel : Panel
{
    public DBPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

As you are trying to create nice GUI as such, may I suggest creating a custom control that combines both the panel and the label and supports double buffering as well.

Example:

```
class FancyLabel : Panel
{

    private bool IsMouseEntered;

    public FancyLabel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        UpdateStyles();
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(205, 205, 205);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        IsMouseEntered = true;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        IsMouseEntered = false;
        Invalidate();
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true)]
    public override string Text { get => base.Text; set => base.Text = value; }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Graphics G = e.Graphics;
        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

        SolidBrush bkBrush = IsMouseEntered ? new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(125, 170, 170, 170)) : new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(125, 45, 45, 45));

        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);

        G.FillRectangle(bkBrush, rec);

        SolidBrush txtBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };

        G.DrawString(Text, Font, txtBrush, rec, sf);

        bkBrush.Dispose();
        txtBrush.Dispose();
        sf.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't even heard of custom controls or double buffering so this helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I ended up replacing the Panel and Label with a Button, previously I didn't know the Button had an opacity property and had resorted to using the Panel and Label.